# Concatenate 2 rows into one in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, union

I have a very simple data structure with just 3 tables:

- requests
- employees
- teams

Basically, what I need is to concatenate 2 different SQL selects into one (so that the query could return just one row).

If there's an employee associated with a request, then return their name (title) and concatenate it with ' / '.

Then, if there's a responsible team for the request, return its title too.

Finally, concatenate these 2 properties into one

The best I could do is:

```
(SELECT CONCAT(e.title, ' / ') FROM employees AS e
    WHERE e.id = (SELECT r.resposible_employee_id FROM requests AS r WHERE r.id = 1))
UNION    
(SELECT t.title FROM teams AS t
    WHERE t.id = (SELECT r.responsible_team_id FROM requests AS r WHERE r.id = 1))
```

But it returns 2 rows instead of one

I could do the concatenation separately by querying the DB twice, but that's not what I'm looking for. I want to query the DB just once.

For your convenience, here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e13b42/5)

The query should return the below just as one row

```
John Doe / Johns team
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for the sample fiddle, a single row however is probably not enough to accurately illustrate the full requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is something like the following what you're after?

```
select 
    Concat_Ws(' / ',
        (select title from employees e where e.id=r.resposible_employee_id),
        (select title from teams t where t.id=r.responsible_team_id)
    )
from requests r 
where id=1
```

See [Modified SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e13b42/11)

Also suspect *respo(n)sible_employee_id* is a typo

Comment: Hello, thanks a million for the answer. The query looks so elegant and works just fine.
Yep, there's a typo, but that's a mock db, doesn't really matter

Comment: Well, the real DB seem obsolete and there's no such function.
Could you rewrite the most generic solution please?

Comment: Assumed you were fine with `concat_ws` as you provided a SQL2017 Fiddle, but just use 'concat` and add `' / '` between the sub-queries as you used originally.

Comment: From what I can gather, the main advantage of `concat_ws` over a simple `concat` is a feature that the former uses delimiter only if both arguments are not null, plain `concat` concatenates irrespectively. If I put `' / '` between the sub-queries and **team** is null, it gives `employeeName /`. On the other hand, if **employee** is null, it returns `/ teamName` . But I bet there's no readable fix for that, so I just used `' / '` in the first sub-query (since it's much less likely that team is null and employee is not).

Comment: There are a few elegant workarounds I can think of, using `nullif` or `outer apply` instead of in-line subqueries - hard to really understand and test though with (as I mentioned above) only a single row of data. You might perhaps concat it to the beginning of each and then *remove* it from the beginning of the final string using `stuff`

Comment: Could you please clarify the solution using `stuff`?

Comment: Did it myself, not sure about the result though

Answer (score 1):

You can perform a couple of outer joins with the related tables. For example:

```
SELECT 
  case when e.id is null
    then coalesce(t.title, 'no information')
    else case when t.id is null then e.title 
           else concat(r.resposible_employee_id, ' / ', t.title) 
         end
    end
FROM requests r
LEFT JOIN employees e on e.id = r.resposible_employee_id
LEFT JOIN teams t on t.id = r.responsible_team_id
WHERE r.id = 1
```

Result:

```
2 / Johns team
```

See running example at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e13b42/19).

The `CASE` expression in the `SELECT` clause should account for all possible combinations of found/not found data in the related tables. Tweak as needed.